# creating conditional axis labels in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a data frame like this:

```
Status      hour
Cancelled   11
NA          11
Cancelled   22
NA          10
Cancelled   7
NA          6
NA          22
Cancelled   6
```

I want to create a graph as shown below, I want to label the x axis based on the time slot choosen:

```
#   0-4 --> Mid Night
#   4-8 --> Early Morning
#   8-12 --> Morning
#   12-16 --> After noon
#   16-20 --> Evening
#   20-24 --> Night
```

expected graph(let's assume orange portion of the graph shows NA , blue shows Cancelled):
[image]

I have absolutely no idea how to achieve this, any clues would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe try using a stacked bar graph like shown at: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/histogram_multihist.html?highlight=hist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start this question off you first need to count up all of the occurrences of `'Cancelled'` and `'nan'` in each time interval. But before that, I'll set up some data:

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO("""
Status      hour
Cancelled   1
Cancelled   11
NA          11
NA          13
Cancelled   22
NA          10
Cancelled   17
Cancelled   18
Cancelled   19
Cancelled   7
NA          6
NA          22
Cancelled   6
"""), header=1)
```

Right, now we can loop over the time categories and do our counting

```
values = {}
for i in range(6):
    values[i] = {}

    status = df.loc[(df['hour'] > i*4) & (df['hour'] <= (i+1)*4), 'Status']

    values[i]['Cancelled'] = status.str.contains('Cancelled').sum()
    values[i]['nan'] = status.isnull().sum()
```

Doing the plot isn't then much work

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

for i in range(6):
    ax.bar(i, values[i]["Cancelled"], color='C0')
    ax.bar(i, values[i]["nan"], color='C1', bottom=values[i]["Cancelled"])

ax.set_xticks(np.r_[:6])
ax.set_xticklabels(['Mid night',
                   'Early Morning',
                   'Morning',
                   'After noon',
                   'Evening',
                   'Night'], rotation=45)

fig.tight_layout()
```

This gave me the following:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! For your own learning process please make sure you understand what I've done and why it works :)

Comment: Thank you so much again! Can you please tell me the best book or the best online tutorials for a beginner. I am struggling to learn python :)

Comment: You're welcome. I guess it really depends what you want to use Python for. My go to reference has always been [this book](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/). However, by the same author, for a complete beginner [this text may be more appropriate](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jakevdp/WhirlwindTourOfPython/blob/master/Index.ipynb)

Comment: I need to learn python for data science.  Thank you so much again for all your help.